# Connect two dropdown filters to one search button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, dropdown

I have two dropdowns that are filtering, but they filter as you drop them down and make selections. I have a search button that I would like to hook them both to. So you just saw a change in results once, after you pressed the button. I think i have all the logic i need here  But im not sure exactly how to hook up the button 
note: i know i have alot of logic in the render, but im just trying to make it work first

So far this is what I have:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          developers: [],
          filterCountry: "All locations",
          filterSkills: "All skills"
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch('API')
        .then(features =>  features.json())
        .then(developers => {
          this.setState({  developers })   
        })
      }

      filterCountry(e){
        this.setState({filterCountry: e })
      }

      filterSkills(e){
        this.setState({filterSkills: e })
      }

      render() {

        let developers = this.state.developers.features   

        if (!developers ){
          return null
        }

        if (this.state.filterCountry && this.state.filterSkills) {
             developers = developers.filter( developer => { 
             return this.state.filterCountry === 'All locations' ||   
      developer.properties.continent.includes(this.state.filterCountry)
          });


             developers = developers.filter( developer => { 
             return this.state.filterSkills === 'All skills' || 
          developer.properties.skills.includes(this.state.filterSkills)
          });  
        }
   return (
         <div>
            <div>
              <ControlSelect
                onChange={this.filterCountry.bind(this)} 
                value={this.state.filterCountry}
                options={options_dd1}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block mr24">
              <ControlSelect
                onChange={this.filterSkills.bind(this)} 
                value={this.state.filterSkills}
                options={options_dd2}
              />
            </div>
            <button>Search</button>
          </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            {developers.map(developer => {
              return (
              <div key={developer.id}">
                {developer.properties.name}
                {developer.properties.description}
                {developer.properties.skills}
              </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       )}
    )}
)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why can't you add that logic into the `onClick` for the `button`?

Comment: thats the part im kinda confused about.. im not sure how to construct the onclick

Comment: A bit more detail about what's happening with your code would help. What are these `ControlSelect` components and where is the code for them? What is `.includes()`?

Comment: the control selects just generate the drop down menus ( the code for these components is not really needed to tackle the button issue).. , and includes is a javascript method that determines whether an array includes a certain element,

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with what you have is that once the filtering is done, there is no way to get the original list of developers back. You can create an 'original list' or developers and a new `filteredList`, which could be actually used by the render method to show data.

Basically, in your initial render, the `developers` key in your state is the default loaded from fetch and will get rendered in its entirety. Once you click the `button`, the `doSearch` method will modify the state and remove developers. This will cause the render to be called and show the new filtered list.

Otherwise, there's a few minor things things taht I have commented below.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      developers: [],
      filterCountry: "All locations",
      filterSkills: "All skills"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('API')
    .then(features =>  features.json())
    .then(developers => {
      this.setState({  developers })   
    })
  }

  filterCountry(e){
    this.setState({filterCountry: e })
  }

  filterSkills(e){
    this.setState({filterSkills: e })
  }

  doSearch() {
    // Create copy of state (you had a `.filtered` in your code, which doesn't make sense as developers is an array so it will have no `filtered` property unless you modified the prototype
    let developers = this.state.developers.slice()   

    // This if block is pointless, because you start with a default state in the constructor (so unless your ControlSelect have a falsy option, this will always evaluate to `true`)

    if (this.state.filterCountry && this.state.filterSkills) {
         // THis will match EITHER country OR skills. You can change to && if wanted.
         developers = developers.filter( developer => { 
         return this.state.filterCountry === 'All locations' ||   
  developer.properties.continent.includes(this.state.filterCountry) || this.state.filterSkills === 'All skills'
  || developer.properties.skills.includes(this.state.filterSkills)
      });
    this.setState({ developers })
    }
  }

  render() {
return (
     <div>
        <div>
          <ControlSelect
            onChange={this.filterCountry.bind(this)} 
            value={this.state.filterCountry}
            options={options_dd1}
            value={this.state.filterCountry}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="inline-block mr24">
          <ControlSelect
            onChange={this.filterSkills.bind(this)} 
            value={this.state.filterSkills}
            options={options_dd2}
            value={this.state.filterSkills}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.doSearch.bind(this)}>Search</button>
      </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        {/* Now the developers contains stuff that was filtered in search */}
        {this.state.developers.map(developer => {
          return (
          <div key={developer.id}>
            {developer.properties.name}
            {developer.properties.description}
            {developer.properties.skills}
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   )}
)}
)
```

Comment: this definitely looks like it should work, but im getting "this.state.developers.map is not a function" error

Comment: Do a `console.log` on `this.state.developers` to see what it is.